# How to create different navigation for registered users in WooThemes Canvas?

Tags: themes, navigation, menus

I'm building a website with wordpress and the Canvas Theme (from WooThemes).

I'm using the Top navigation for displaying items when a user is logged in.
When the user is not logged in, you can see only 'become a member' and 'login'.
When the user logins, he/she sees another navigation with other menu items.

I thought of the following solution:

1. register a new navigation.
2. apply a hook which checks if a user is logged in or not
3. According to the result, apply the navigation for registred users, otherwise show other.

I put this code in my *functions.php*:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_top_menu_myisa', 10 );

function register_top_menu_myisa() {
    $menus = array(
                'top-menu-myisa' => __( 'Top Menu MyISA', 'woothemes' )
            );
    register_nav_menus( $menus );
}

add_action( 'woo_top', 'custom_top_navigation', 10 );

function custom_top_navigation() {
    if ( function_exists( 'has_nav_menu' ) && has_nav_menu( 'top-menu' ) ) {

        if(is_user_logged_in()) {
            $top_menu = 'top-menu-myisa';
        } else {
            $top_menu = 'top-menu';
        }

    echo '<div id="top">';
    echo '<div class="col-full">';
    echo '<h3 class="top-menu">' . woo_get_menu_name( $top_menu ) . '</h3>';
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'depth' => 6, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container' => 'ul', 'menu_id' => 'top-nav', 'menu_class' => 'nav top-navigation fl', 'theme_location' => $top_menu ) );
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

The first function registers the new navigation.
The second function contains the logic for deciding which top navigation should be displayed.

**However: when I look at my site, it displays both menu's (the one for non logged in users and the one for logged in users)**
[image: Two navigation menu's displayed]

**How can I modify the code so that it displays one top navigation menu, based on if the user is logged in or not?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. I don't know the exact cause, but I'll explain exactly what I did.

I was using Wordpress 3.5. After I updated to 3.6, my navigation code started to work.
It's also important to mention that I did use W3C Total Cache, but removed it (before applying this code), and set the `WP_DEBUG` flag to `false`. I removed W3C Total Cache only because I was experimenting with it.

This is the final code:

```
/* = Register the MyISA top navigation.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

add_action( 'init', 'isa_register_top_menu_myisa');

function isa_register_top_menu_myisa() {
    if(function_exists('has_nav_menu') && !has_nav_menu('top-menu-myisa')) {
    $menus = array(
                'top-menu-myisa' => __('Top Menu MyISA', 'woothemes')
            );
    register_nav_menus($menus);
    }
}


/* = Determine the top navigation to display.

When a user is logged in, the MyISA top navigation is displayed.
Otherwise the default top navigation wil be visible.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

add_action('woo_top', 'woo_top_navigation');

function woo_top_navigation() {
    if (function_exists('has_nav_menu') && has_nav_menu('top-menu')) {

        if(is_user_logged_in()) {
            $top_menu = 'top-menu-myisa';
        } else {
            $top_menu = 'top-menu';
        }

        echo '<div id="top">';
        echo '<div class="col-full">';
        echo '<h3 class="top-menu">' . woo_get_menu_name($top_menu) . '</h3>';

        wp_nav_menu( array( 'depth' => 6, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container' => 'ul', 'menu_id' => 'top-nav', 'menu_class' => 'nav top-navigation fl', 'theme_location' => $top_menu ) );

        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('init','wpsites_members_menu');

function wpsites_members_menu(){
if(is_user_logged_in()){
    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args' , 'logged_in_nav_menu' );
}
}
```

Display Different Nav Menu For Logged in and Logged Out Users

Source: http://wpsites.net/web-design/members-nav-menu-logged-in-members/

```
function logged_in_nav_menu( $args ) {
if ( $args['theme_location'] == 'primary' ) { 
    $args['menu'] = 'members'; 
}
return $args;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately this didn't work for me. I keep getting the same result.